# Regexpression OR

Tags: javascript, regex

I have next string:

```
1 2 OR 3 4 OR 5 OR 6 7 OR 8
```

I need to separate it on different parts according OR using regexps, for example from this line I need to get next:

```
1
2 OR 3
4 OR 5 OR 6
8 OR 8

//1 (2 OR 3) (4 OR 5 OR 6) (7 OR 8)
```

How to do it - thanks!)

Sorry, but forgot to mention, that here can be not only digits: first second OR third forth OR fifth OR sixth seventh OR eight

Comment: I tried /([^\s"]+|"[^"]*")( +OR +([^\s"]+|"[^"]*"))+/i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple regex should work:

```
var str = '1 2 OR 3 4 OR 5 OR 6 7 OR 8';
str.match(/\w+( OR \w+)*/g);
```

Comment: Sorry, but forgot to mention, that here can be nor only digits: first second OR third forth OR fifth OR sixth seventh OR eigth

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression that matches a number followed any number of `OR` and another number:

```
var s = '1 2 OR 3 4 OR 5 OR 6 7 OR 8';

var re = /\d+(?: OR \d+)*/g;
var m;
while ((m = re.exec(s)) != null) {
  console.log(m[0]);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/q5fw6/

Comment: Sorry, but forgot to mention, that here can be nor only digits: first second OR third forth OR fifth OR sixth seventh OR eigths

Comment: ""nor only digits"? what do you mean by that? can you provide an example?

Comment: @Simha: Aha, then just change `\d` in the regular expression to `[^ ]` to match any non-space characters instead of just digits. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/q5fw6/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
x.replace(/(\d+)\s+(\d+)/g, "$1\n$2");
```

where `x` is `"1 2 OR 3 4 OR 5 OR 6 7 OR 8"`

Output will be:

```
1 
2 OR 3 
4 OR 5 OR 6 
7 OR 8
```

Comment: Sorry, but forgot to mention, that here can be nor only digits: first second OR third forth OR fifth OR sixth seventh OR eigth

Answer (score 0):

This could be what you need:

```
(?:^|(?<=\d ))(\d+(?: +OR +\d+)*)(?=(?: +\d|$))
```

Will output the following matches:

```
[Match number 1]
[Capture Group 1] '1' found at character 1

[Match number 2]
[Capture Group 1] '2 OR 3' found at character 3

[Match number 3]
[Capture Group 1] '4 OR 5 OR 6' found at character 10

[Match number 4]
[Capture Group 1] '7 OR 8' found at character 22
```

Comment: Sorry, but forgot to mention, that here can be nor only digits: first second OR third forth OR fifth OR sixth seventh OR eigth